# StackOverflowError on Groovy while passing a generic class argument to method

Tags: generics, groovy, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij IDEA 12 with Groovy plug-in enabled.
I'm getting StackOverflowError on make on this case:

`OItem.java:`

```
public interface OItem<O extends Order<O, I, ?>, I extends OItem> extends DomainBase, Processable, ValidationListener{
    //Some methods
}
```

`ROItem.java:`

```
public interface ROItem extends OItem<ROrder, ROItem>, DomainBase {
    //Some methods
}
```

The problem is here. When the method takes `ROItem` it compiles:

```
class MyScript {
    static void myMethod(ROItem orderItem) {
        //Empty inside
    }
}
```

but when it takes `OItem`, Groovyc throws SOError:

```
class MyScript {
    static void myMethod(OItem orderItem) {
        //Empty inside
    }
}
```

Full trace is here:

```
Groovyc: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.toString(ClassNode.java:1127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.genericTypeAsString(ClassNode.java:1160)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.toString(ClassNode.java:1134)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.genericTypeAsString(ClassNode.java:1160)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.toString(ClassNode.java:1134)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.toString(ClassNode.java:1120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.toString(ClassNode.java:1139)
    ...
```

This part repeats 257 times:

```
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.genericTypeAsString(ClassNode.java:1160)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.toString(ClassNode.java:1134)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.toString(ClassNode.java:1120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.toString(ClassNode.java:1139)
```

Comment: What version of Groovy are you using?

Comment: Do you mean the groovy dependency in the project?

Comment: My guess is because your generics are recursive, it is failing when it tries to print an error in your types

Comment: Thanks tim. There is a recursice generic in my types: `O` is used in `OItem` and `Order` both. But what can be the error which Groovy tries to print? I'm using those types without a problem in Java.

Comment: Seems similar to [JENKINS-34525](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34525) and (link lost) GRECLIPSE-1234.